# Async Functions returning undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, ecmascript-next

Im working on fetching data from a GraphQL Server and I'm attempting to implement ES7 `Async` functions through babel. I'm currently receiving `undefined` in the console and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
/**
 * [transport creates call to server with isomorphic-fetch]
 * @param  {[String]} path        [url to hit with request]
 * @param  {[Object]} query       [The GraphQL query/mutation]
 * @param  {[Object]} queryParams = {} [Params to pass into query]
 * @return {[Promise]}            [Promise containing payload]
 */
 //function that returns a promise
 export function transport (path, query, queryParams = {}) {
     return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
       return fetch(path, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'content-type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                 query,
                 queryParams
             })
         })
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(response => {
           if(response.errors) {
             return error(response.errors);
           }
           return resolve(response.data);
         })
         .catch(error);
     });
 }
```

```js
import { transport } from './utils/transport.js';

/**
 * [reachGraphQL Makes queres or mutations against GraphQL]
 * @param  {[String]} path        [path to the GraphQL server]
 * @param  {[Object]} query       [The query that GraphQL will use to fetch your data]
 * @param  {[object]} queryParams =  {} [Should contain object with different query params]
 * @return {[Object]}             [Data that was queried or mutated]
 */
//Heres Where I'm awaiting a promise from the transport function
export function reachGraphQL (path, query, queryParams = {}) {
  async () => {
    try{
      let response = await transport(path, query, queryParams);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your promise implements resolve but does not call reject on error.  Could your code be swallowing an exception?

Comment: not completely sure, I think its the manner in which I used async on reachGraphQL()

Comment: Where is 'error' defined?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the top module

Comment: It looks like if response.errors is truths, your promise will swallow an exception saying that 'error is undefined'

Comment: I was able to fix it. It turned out to be the fact that I was using the async keyword in the wrong location.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! And what is `error`, did you mean `reject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reachGraphQL` just defines an `async` arrow function but doesn't do anything with it. And it doesn't `return` anything. Rather, it should be `async` itself:

```
export async function reachGraphQL (path, query, queryParams = {}) {
    try {
        return await transport(path, query, queryParams);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: They causes the following:
bundle.js:53 Promise {_d: Object}
bundle.js:125 ReferenceError: error is not defined(…)
but doesn't respond with the retrieved information.

Comment: As stated in the comments, `.catch(error);` is a problem.